# Encrypting connection strings causes App Pool to stop

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config, connection-string

I want to encrypt my connection strings when I first run my code. I call the code below from the Global.asax.

When I try this on my machine, the connectionstrings are encrypted, but when I place this on the server it causes the app pool to stop. I can't really tell why this happens because the connection is reset.

Is this a problem with the write settings of a file? How can I make this work on the web server?

```
var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
var section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;

if (section == null)
{
    return;
}


if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
    return;
}

section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");

config.Save();
```

Comment: Editing a web.config file should cause the application pool to recycle.  Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: No I don't think so, because no changes are made to the web.config..

Comment: Surely this is what your code is doing?  Encrypting the connection strings in the web.config?

Comment: Yes it is, it will alter my web.config and will encrypt it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, and that's what I'm saying.  Altering the web.config will cause the app pool to recycle.  You are running code in an app domain that you then restart once you change the config.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this is an old question but I just now ran across it.*

If you encrypted the connection strings in the web.config on your local machine before copying the web.config file over to your web server, **then I'm assuming that's the problem**. Unless both machines are using the same IIS RSA key (which I'm not even sure is possible and it's probably unlikely), the destination machine won't be able to decrypt the connection string cipher because it was encoded with the source machine's key.

**Therefore, you must encrypt the web.config settings from the target machine itself.**

By the way, I got confused by your comments under the question. Invoking the config.Save() method *will* modify the web.config file, even if the content didn't change. In the example code above, the content should have changed anyway because you encrypted the connectionStrings section before saving. In order for IIS to utilize an updated web.config, it has to recycle its application pool first. This is partly why, by default, IIS automatically recycles the associated app pool when it detects a web.config change.